# ¿Cuál es la función de destroy en tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Comencé desarrollando un juego en Python que necesita ventanas, lo que me lleva a hacer uso de `tkinter`. La idea es utilizar una ventana principal que desaparece y da espacio a otras, de acuerdo a las acciones del juego, y que también desaparecen, de esa forma sucesivamente.

La incógnita que tengo tiene que ver con el procedimiento de almacenamiento de Python de los widgets, por ejemplo, cuando escribo `w.destroy()`, ¿Estoy sacando a w de la memoria del computador o simplemente lo estoy haciendo invisible en su widget padre para poder escribir sobre él?

Comment: Hola @dougjim. Tal y como dices, al ejecutar un `w.destroy()` estas eliminando el espacio de memoria asignado previamente en la memoria de tu equipo ya que la función de destroy() es eliminar la ventana. Mientras tanto, existe la función `w.withdraw()` la cuál esconde la ventana pero no la elimina. Consulta [este enalce](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-python-tkinter-root-window#:~:text=In%20order%20to%20destroy%20the,close%20the%20root%20window%20immediately.) donde se explica esto mismo.

Comment: @RuthIsRoot no creo que borre del todo el widget o ventana. Al menos el objeto encargado de comunicar el widget con Python seguiria existiendo.

Comment: @Date S. Bajo mi opinión, la función `withdraw` seguira almacenando en memoria el espacio del widget. Mientras que `destroy` elimina el espacio en memoria que almacenaba para la ventana (0x......). Esa es la principal diferencia entre estas funciones

Comment: @RuthIsRoot no creo que te equivoques en eso. Pero el objeto que comunica el widget con Python (Tk, Toplevel, Entry, etc) supongo que seguiria existiendo hasta que su contador de referencias sea 0.

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas. Tengo ahora bastante claras las funciones de destroy y de withdraw.